# How to join multiple string tokens into one token by flex/lex?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, flex-lexer, lex

In flex/lex, I want to match multiple string tokens into one string token. How should I write the flex/lex rule?

Now my string matching rule is:

```
union {
  char *literal;
  int token;
};

\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"       {
                          yylval.literal = strndup(yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);
                          return T_STRING_CONSTANT;
                        }
```

This rule match below source into 3 tokens:

```
// source code

"hello world," " goodbye world," " my love"
```

How could I join them into one token ?

```
"hello world, goodbye world, my love"
```

Comment: What if you join the tokens for individual literals on grammar level? IMHO, this is easier to achieve than doing it in the lexer. Otherwise, you had to modify your reg ex. for the literal to consume separating white spaces (and what else) as well... (and still have to fiddle to remove the optional separating white spaces afterwards).

Comment: @Scheff, thanks, I really implement it in this way, problem solved.

Comment: That's what `YYMORE` is for.